# How to write 10⁰ (10^0) with siunitx?

Tags: siunitx

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\num[print-zero-exponent=true, print-unity-mantissa=false]{1e0}

\end{document}
```

**Output with pdfLaTeX:**

[image]

Comment: `\qty{10}{\degree}`?

Comment: @Rmano Not sure the OP wants degrees.  I'm thinking "ten to the power zero" as in "1".

Comment: Please clarify what you're trying to achieve: `10^0` or `10[degree symbol]`?

Comment: It seems to me that this is a bug. You may want to file a report at `siunitx`' [bug tracker](https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/issues). (Or I can do it if you do not have and do not want a Github account.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Corrected with version 3.0.8 of siunitx.

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\num[print-zero-exponent=true, print-unity-mantissa=false]{1e0}

\num[print-zero-exponent=true, print-unity-mantissa=false]{e0}

\end{document}
```

**Output with pdfLaTeX:**

[image]

Thank you guys for your help and Joseph Wright for your amazing package.

Answer (score 2):

For older `siunitx` installations, circa 2021-03-07, this would work.  But that is no longer the case, I have been informed.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\num[retain-zero-exponent]{e0}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: When was the last time you updated your TeX distribution and, more specifically, the `siunitx` package? :-) Starting with version 3.0 of `siunitx`, released earlier this month, your MWE outputs `1\times10^0`, not `10^0`.

Comment: @Mico `siunitx 2021/03/27 v2.8c`  Who would have thought?  Overtaken by events!

Comment: Adding to Mico's comment, the option is now documented as `print-zero-exponent`, as used by the OP.

Comment: @schtandard - My point was actually rather different. Incidentally, both `print-zero-exponent` and `retain-zero-exponent`work under version 3.0.x of `siunitx`.

Comment: @Mico I understand and I did not mean to suggest that my point was also your point. However, since version 3 `retain-zero-exponent` is now an undocumented option and, in my opinion, should be avoided in answers here (expecially when the OP uses the documented equivalent).

Comment: @schtandard - No worries. Just out of curiosity: Would you know whether there's an option in version 3 of `siunitx` to have `\num{e0}` generate `10^0` (as is shown in Steven's screenshot) rather than `1\times10^0`?

Comment: @Mico As I wrote [above](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/599081/#comment1501874_599081), I think this is a bug and should work as in version 2. Joseph Wright [seems to agree](https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/issues/459).